# Performance of Kivy function canvas.clear() degrades over time

Tags: python, kivy

I am creating a program which basically comes down to creating 2d-meshes by adding and moving points.
Everything is working OK, but the performance of the program degrades over time.

The graphics are being drawn by the following code snippet:

```
   self.canvas.clear()
   self.draw_grid()
   self.draw_img()

   for region in self.visible_regions:
       points = add_u1v1(self.to_canvas([(region.origin[0], region.origin[1])] + region.points))
       idx = range(int(len(points)/4))
       with self.canvas:
           self.canvas.add(colors[region.type])
           Mesh(vertices=points, indices=idx, mode='triangle_fan')
           Color(0.3, 0.3, 0.3)
           Mesh(vertices=points, indices=idx, mode='line_loop')

   with self.canvas:
       for obj in self.visible_objects:
           self.canvas.add(obj.color)
           obj.draw(self.scale, self.center_x+self.xoffset, self.center_y + self.yoffset)
```

I am only running this part of the code IF a graphics element has changed.

In order to find the cause of the degradation, I am forcing an update every 1/120:th of a second.
I have tested the executing times of different parts of my program, and have concluded that the problem is: **self.canvas.clear()**

When starting the program, **self.canvas.clear()** takes about 0.1 ms to run, but If I leave the program running (*Without changing anything about the entities being drawn*), the time it takes to clear the canvas quickly increases to > 100ms.

During this testing, the drawing instructions stay exactly the same. Same number of meshes/visible_objects and they are drawn .

I can't figure out why. Any ideas why this is happening, and how I should do things differently to get rid the problem with self.canvas.clear()?

EDIT: Maybe "quickly" is a bit of an over-statement. After about 10-20 min the execution time of self.canvas.clear() is > 100 ms, and the program is nearly unusable.

Answer (score 1):

After digging deeper I found the answer to this problem myself.

For some reason, when doing `canvas.clear()`, the color instructions are not cleared. So the canvas "children" list just grows larger and larger over time....

So it is not enough to do `canvas.clear()`. You also need to do:

```
self.canvas.children = [self.canvas.before, self.canvas.after]
# Alternatively
self.canvas.children[1:-1] = []
```

(not sure if `canvas.clear()` does more than just clearing the list of children, so I will keep `canvas.clear()` as well for now)

Comment: You should report this as a bug. According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html#kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas.clear), the `clear()` command should clear every Instruction in the canvas, leaving it clean.